# Springboot components do not "reset" when I send a new request?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, asynchronous, autowired

I have a Springboot application exposing a simple REST api, with several layers and autowired @Components, and I send a HTTP POST request to its @RestController through Postman, and in one of the subsequent components I'm doing stuff with the received data.

The problem is that when I send more requests in postman after the first has returned, the components seem to still contain information from the previous request that has already returned a response... How to avoid this? I want every request to be a "clean slate". It's almost as if it's not cleaning up when its done.. It's so annoying because I dont even know how to formulate the problem but I hope you understand.

In the following code the "actual_imported_rows" keeps increasing for subsequent requests:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
@Slf4j
public class StrekningImporter {

    int expected_num_rows;
    int actual_imported_rows;

    HashMap<Long, StrekningEntity> successfulStrekning = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<FailedImportEntry> unsuccessfulStrekning = new ArrayList<>();

    public HashMap<Long, StrekningEntity> startImport(Sheet sheet, HashMap<Long, RegulativEntity> regulativHashMap,
        HashMap<Long, SambandEntity> sambandHashMap) throws FailedImport {

        expected_num_rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();

        System.out.println("ACTUAL IMPORT SIZE: " + actual_imported_rows);

        int rowNum = 0;
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            // Skip header
            if (rowNum == 0) {
                rowNum++;
                rows.next();
            }

            Row currentRow = rows.next();

            try {
                StrekningEntity strekning = iterateRow(currentRow, regulativHashMap, sambandHashMap);
                successfulStrekning.put((long) strekning.getId(), strekning);
                actual_imported_rows += 1;
            } catch (FailedImportEntry failedImportEntry) {
                unsuccessfulStrekning.add(failedImportEntry);
                rowNum++;
                continue;
            }
            rowNum++;
        }

        log.info("Imported Strekning : " + actual_imported_rows + " out of: " + expected_num_rows);

        if (unsuccessfulStrekning.size() > 0) {
            throw new FailedImport("Strekning", unsuccessfulStrekning);
        }

        return successfulStrekning;
    }

    private StrekningEntity iterateRow(Row currentRow, HashMap<Long, RegulativEntity> regulativHashMap,
        HashMap<Long, SambandEntity> sambandHashMap) throws FailedImportEntry {

        int strekning_id = 0;
        String rutekode = "";
        String vegkode = "";
        int samband_id = 0;
        String oppdragsgiver = "";
        String fergeleie_fra = "";
        String fergeleie_til = "";
        double distanse = 0;
        int reisetid = 0;
        int regulativ_id = 0;
        int sone = 0;
        int sonepaslag = 0;
        String vegnummer = "";
        String merknad = "";
        LocalDate gyldig_fra = null;
        LocalDate gyldig_til = null;

        StrekningEntity strekningEntity = null;

        int colIndex = 0;
        try {
            int lastCellNum = currentRow.getLastCellNum();
            for (; colIndex < lastCellNum; colIndex++) {
                Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(colIndex);
                switch (colIndex) {
                    case 0:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            strekning_id = (int) currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            rutekode = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            vegkode = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            samband_id = (int) currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            fergeleie_fra = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            fergeleie_til = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 9:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            distanse = currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            reisetid = (int) currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            regulativ_id = (int) currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            sone = (int) currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            sonepaslag = (int) currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            vegnummer = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            merknad = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            gyldig_fra = currentCell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue().toLocalDate();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        if (currentCell != null) {
                            gyldig_til = currentCell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue().toLocalDate();
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            SambandEntity samband = sambandHashMap.get((long) samband_id);
            RegulativEntity regulativ = regulativHashMap.get((long) regulativ_id);

            strekningEntity = new StrekningEntity((short) strekning_id, samband, fergeleie_fra, fergeleie_til,
                (int) distanse, reisetid, regulativ, null, (short) sone, (short) sonepaslag, false, merknad, gyldig_fra,
                gyldig_til, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FailedImportEntry failedImportEntry = new FailedImportEntry(currentRow.getRowNum(), colIndex,
                "class: " + e.getClass() + " | message: " + e.getMessage());
            throw failedImportEntry;
        }

        return strekningEntity;
    }
}
```

Any help or hints where the problem lies would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Spring services and components should be stateless. Can you post the classes that seem to keep a state from the previous request?

Comment: why are you changing the component state on each request? That should not be done

Comment: updated main post with code of the component causing trouble